# Strange backout behaviour

Tags: mercurial

I cannot reproduce the same results as provided at https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/Backout

After I performed `hg backout -r 1` as said there - no new changeset appears and I just have a file modified in `tip`.

Why is that?

ps: I'm using `hg 1.9`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was changed in Mercurial 1.7. See https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/WhatsNew. Apparently, you can now use `--merge` to get the previous behavior.

Comment: I'm not sure that `--merge` could change behaviour to old one, but thanks for the reference